# How to Position Text at the Bottom of the div?

Tags: html, position

I'm trying to position a line of copyright text in my menu at the bottom of the DIV so that the line aligns with bottom of the image on the right. You can see it here:

Site with original issue: stephenpilkington dot com (having this linked could be considered SPAM).

Code from comments:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <!-- TITLE --> 
    <a href="#"> 
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/this-is-a.png" alt="" /> 
    </a> 
    <! -- END TITLE --> 
    <!-- NAVIGATION --> 
    <ul id="navigation"> 
        <li><?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?></li>
    </ul> 
    <!-- END NAVIGATION --> 
    <!-- CREDITS --> 
    <div id="credits"> 
        <div class="sub"> © Stephen Pilkington 2015 
      </a> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
    <!-- END CREDITS --> 
</div> 
<!-- end sidebar -->
```

Image from comments:

[image: Image from comments]

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: what code do you suggest I paste? This is a visual question.

Comment: I suggest that you post the code you have that isn't working. You can also post a screen shot in your question if you like. But only posting a link to your site doesn't fly, if for no other reason than your question loses all value once your issue is resolved.

Comment: Try applying some Cascading Style Sheet (css) in your code.

Comment: here is the code of the menu part of the page:

Comment: <div id="sidebar">


 <!-- TITLE -->
  
 <a href="#">
  <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/this-is-a.png" alt="" />
 </a>
 
 <! -- END TITLE -->
 
 
 <!-- NAVIGATION -->
 
 <ul id="navigation">
  <li><?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?></li>
 </ul> 
  
 <!-- END NAVIGATION --> 
 

 <!-- CREDITS -->

 <div id="credits">
  <div class="sub">
   © Stephen Pilkington 2015
   </a>
  </div>   
 </div>  
 
 <!-- END CREDITS -->
 
 
</div> <!-- end sidebar -->

Comment: here's a screen shot: http://postimg.org/image/d3kbb130j/

Answer (score 0):

Try moving
                © Stephen Pilkington 2015

```
    </div>
```

to be under

```
<img class="nature alignnone wp-image-17 size-medium" style="" src="http://stephenpilkington.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/me-215x300.jpg" alt="me" width="215" height="300" title="">
```

It's a little hard to tell right now but that should be it.